# Why is one variable changed by my function while the other is not?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm facing some trouble with Python. I defined a simple function which takes two lists (both include tuples of two) as argument. During the function, tuples are added to `addmap` gradually, while a list called `toberemoved` is deleted from `removemap` in the very end of the function.

Both arguments represent lists from outside the function. While  the list `addmap` is changed after the function ran, `removemap` remains the same. This is weird because if I print out `removemap` within the function, it displays my desired result. I just don't see it outside. What is going on here? Thank you!

```py
def loescheeinzelgaenger(removemap, addmap):
    toberemoved = [] #lists all the list values which should be removed from the removemap and added to the addmap
    for row in range(shape[0]):
        for column in range(shape[1]):
            if (row,column) in removemap:
                # define 4 neighbours
                n1 = (row - 1, column)
                n2 = (row, column - 1)
                n3 = (row + 1, column)
                n4 = (row, column + 1)
                if intersection([n1,n2,n3,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n1,n2,n3],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n2,n3,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n1, n3,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n1,n2,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
    removemap = [x for x in removemap if x not in toberemoved]
    print(removemap) #it's changed here

#further down:

print(grassMap) #initial
print(waterMap) #initial

loescheeinzelgaenger(waterMap,grassMap)

print(grassMap) #changed
print(waterMap) #unchanged
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code explicitly alters `addmap` in place:

```
                addmap.append((row, column))
```

This appends to the existing list.  However, you use a different "technology" to work with the local `removemap`:

```
removemap = [x for x in removemap if x not in toberemoved]
```

This says to take the `removemap` passed in, iterate through its elements, filter out the ones you want, and then make a *new* list from those elements.  Finally, assign this new list to the local variable `removemap`.  Since this changes the object reference to the new list, you're no longer working with the reference passed in from the calling routine ... and *that* `removemap` variable still points to the original list.

To alter your original list, you can carefully use the `remove` method:

```
for rem in toberemoved:
    while rem in removemap:
        removemap.remove(rem)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
removemap = [x for x in removemap if x not in toberemoved]
```

This line creates a new local list that has nothing to do with the list that was passed to the function.

The only obvious solution would be to return it from the function:

```
def loescheeinzelgaenger(removemap, addmap):
    ...    
    return [x for x in removemap if x not in toberemoved]

waterMap = loescheeinzelgaenger(waterMap, grassMap)
```

Comment: Use a return value?

Comment: @MarcoMarss The only obvious solution would be to return it from the function

Comment: i am new to Python, could you please help me out on how to return it? i tried to put the return statement already but there was no effect

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return` statement to get the values you want:

```
def loescheeinzelgaenger(removemap, addmap):
    toberemoved = [] #lists all the list values which should be removed from the removemap and added to the addmap
    for row in range(shape[0]):
        for column in range(shape[1]):
            if (row,column) in removemap:
                # define 4 neighbours
                n1 = (row - 1, column)
                n2 = (row, column - 1)
                n3 = (row + 1, column)
                n4 = (row, column + 1)
                if intersection([n1,n2,n3,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n1,n2,n3],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n2,n3,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n1, n3,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n1,n2,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
    removemap = [x for x in removemap if x not in toberemoved]
    print(removemap) #it's changed here
    return removemap, addmap

 waterMap,grassMap = loescheeinzelgaenger(waterMap,grassMap)
```

You're basically telling Python: of all the things you did in this function I want you to give me these two variables in the state they were at the end of the function

Answer (score 0):

The others have already outlined the line, which cause your behaviour. But I would refactor your code a little bit more: (You used the global variable `shape`)

```py
def loescheeinzelgaenger(removemap, number_of_rows, number_of_columns):
    toberemoved = [] #lists all the list values which should be removed from the removemap and added to the addmap
    addmap = []
    for row in range(number_of_rows):
        for column in range(number_of_columns):
            if (row,column) in removemap:
                # define 4 neighbours
                n1 = (row - 1, column)
                n2 = (row, column - 1)
                n3 = (row + 1, column)
                n4 = (row, column + 1)
                if intersection([n1,n2,n3,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n1,n2,n3],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n2,n3,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n1, n3,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
                elif intersection([n1,n2,n4],removemap) == []:
                    toberemoved.append((row, column))
                    addmap.append((row, column))
    new_removemap = [x for x in removemap if x not in toberemoved]
    return new_removemap, addmap

waterMap, grassMap = loescheeinzelgaenger(waterMap, shape[0], shape[1])
```

And as an additional comment: I would not mix different languages for naming of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can either return your newly created list from your function, and assign the return value to `removemap`as mentioned in other answers, or you can change the list `removemap` in place in your function like this:

```
for x in toberemoved: 
    if x in removemap:
        removemap.remove(x)
```

This way you're changing the actual list that was passed in, not creating a new one.

Comment: In this case, you should catch the possible `ValueError`.